# Expected arrival time for the first person in the decomposition of poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

**Question:**

Customers arrive at a shop according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda > 0$ per hour, with probability $p$ being male and $1-p$ being female. During the first hour $n$ people arrived ($n \ge 1$)

Calculate $\mathrm{E} (Z|A)$, where $Z$ is the arrival time of the first male customer and $A$ is the event that there is at least one male among the $n$ arrived customers

**My attempt:**

Let $S_i$ denote the arrival time of $i$th customer, then $\Pr(Z = S_i) = (1-p)^{i-1}\cdot p$

And when $Z = S_i$, because $S_i$ is distributed as the order statistics from a uniform distribution, we have $Z \sim \mathrm{B}(i, n+1-i)$ (according to wikipedia) and therefore its expectation is $\frac{i}{n+1}$

Finally $\displaystyle \mathrm{E} (Z | A) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(1-p)^{i-1}\cdot p}{1 - (1-p)^n} \cdot \frac{i}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{p}{1-(1-p)^n}\cdot \bigl(\frac{1-p-(1-p)^{n+1}}{p^2} + \frac{1-(n+1)(1-p)^n}{p}\bigr)$

Is my reasoning on the right line? It feels really awkward and the idea only exists vaguely in my head and I don't know how to formalise this. (There are probably errors in the closed form of the series but I want to check if the logic is right first)

Comment: Hint: the arrival times of the male customers are a Poisson process with rate $p\lambda.$